# "undefined handler" from prototype.js line 3877

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prototypejs

A very niche problem:

I sometimes (30% of the time) get an 'undefined handler' javascript error on line 3877 of the prototype.js library (version 1.6.0.2 from google: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js).

Now on this page I have a Google Map and I use the Prototype Window library.

The problem occurs in IE7 and FF3.

This is the info FireBug gives:

```
handler is undefined
? in prototype.js@3871()prototype.js (line 3877)
handler.call(element, event);
```

I switched to a local version of prototypejs and added some debugging in the offending method (createWraper) but the debugging never appears before the error...

I googled around and found 1 other mention of the error on the same line, but no answer so I'm posting it here where maybe, some day someone will have an answer :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out this error also occurs if you accidentally leave on the parenthesis on your observer call:

```
Event.observe(document, 'myapp:application_ready', myapp.MyClass.initApp());
```

instead of

```
Event.observe(document, 'myapp:application_ready', myapp.MyClass.initApp);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I switched to a local version of prototypejs and added some debugging
>   in the offending method (createWraper) but the debugging never appears
>   before the error...

Actually the offending function being called when the error occurs is "wrapper" which is created inside createWrapper (but not called there). Basically what is happening is that you've attached a function as the event handler for an element, and the function doesn't actually exist.

If you're trying to put any debug information in to try and pinpoint which function "doesn't exist" then add your alert messages or firebug console output inside the wrapper function between lines 3871 and 3878.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably cause an error:

```
Event.observe(myElement, 'click', myFunction(myParameters));
```

You should do it like this instead:

```
Event.observe(myElement, 'click', function() { myFunction(myParameters) });
```

Comment: When adding an element with a click event handler to canvas with kineticjs click event got fire without any clicking, wrapping my function inside an anonymous function fixed this for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple solution for **“undefined handler” from prototype.js** error in Prototype is just... fix prototype. I found advice here: https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/407-ie7-i8-report-handler-is-null-or-not-an-object and it's actually working.

Just find line with: 
`handler.call(element, event);` 
and replace with 
`if (handler) handler.call(element, event)`
problem solved with prototype 1.6.0.3 and latest :)

Comment: Adding the line of code you did will prevent the error from happening, but whatever is triggering that is trying to do so on an element that does not exist, so nothing would have happened anyway. this is not a fix